# Returning a String array and assign it to a String array type variable in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

In `Java`, I have a function that needs to return a `String[]` array to be assigned to a variable of `String[]` array type.
How do I do this ?

**The variable:**

```
String[] num;
```

**The function:**

```
String[] numbers(){
  for (int i = 0; i<20; i++){
      numbers[i] = "number";
    }   
 }
```

Comment: `return arrayName` what is the problem in that?

Comment: how come String type array element is assigned to int type?

Comment: sorry, there was this error in the question. i edited it. I just wanted to understand how to return and assign string arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Assign Variable**, here you have to assign variable to method that is returning same type so... `String[] xx = function String[]()`

In your case:

```
String[] num = numbers();
```

**The method** here you have to create array, fill it and return it. Always according to it's signature so if you declare a `function String[] name()` you must `return String[]` to finish function.

In your case:

```
public String[] numbers(){
    String[] numbers = new String[20];
    for (int i = 0; i<20; i++){
        numbers[i] = Integer.toString(i);  // i is an integer, "transform it into string"
    }
    return numbers;
}
```